# Junit runs fine individually, but fails during maven build giving sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException

Tags: maven, spring-boot, authentication, junit, mocking

A junit is testing JMS response from a mockserver. The Junit is unable to find the certificate path during maven build, but finds it and runs with no exception when run individually.

certificate related `application.yml`:

```
bridge:
   conduit:
    keystore:
     type: pkcs12
     password: ENC(l4/yeZUp8n4v7iArP1H9OWeVHUO5JCM2)
     location: src/main/resources/config/certificatessl.p12
jasypt:
  encryptor:
    password: G;SobWzm9Z;zWOMQuUF
```

junit in test class uses following mockserver:

```
mockServer.when(HttpRequest.request("/gateway/spec").withSecure(true).withBody(Mockito.anyString()))
                .respond(HttpResponse.response(myJsonObject));
```

The context loads the mockserver:

```
   @Bean(destroyMethod = "stop")
   @Lazy
   public ClientAndServer mockServer() {

       ConfigurationProperties.deleteGeneratedKeyStoreOnExit(true);
       ClientAndServer mockServer = ClientAndServer.startClientAndServer(7071);
       HttpsURLConnection
               .setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(KeyStoreFactory.keyStoreFactory().sslContext().getSocketFactory());

       return mockServer;
   }
```

`application-cxfconduit.xml`:

```
    <http:conduit name="{/b2b/Services}PreparationPort.http-conduit">
        <http:tlsClientParameters disableCNCheck="true" secureSocketProtocol="TLSv1.2">
            <sec:keyManagers keyPassword="#{environment['bridge.conduit.keystore.password']}">
                <sec:keyStore type="${bridge.conduit.keystore.type}"
                    password="#{environment['bridge.conduit.keystore.password']}"
                    file="${bridge.conduit.keystore.location}" />
            </sec:keyManagers>
        </http:tlsClientParameters>

        <http:client Connection="close" ConnectionTimeout="${bridge.conduit.connectionTimeout:30000}"
            ReceiveTimeout="${bridge.conduit.receiveTimeout:120000}" ProxyServer="${bridge.conduit.proxy.address:}"
            ProxyServerPort="${bridge.conduit.proxy.port:}" ProxyServerType="HTTP" AutoRedirect="true" AllowChunking="false" />

        <http:proxyAuthorization>
            <sec:UserName>"${bridge.conduit.proxy.username:}"</sec:UserName>
            <sec:Password>"${bridge.conduit.proxy.password:}"</sec:Password>
        </http:proxyAuthorization>
    </http:conduit>
```

Why is it giving `sun.security.validator.ValidatorException` only during maven build, whereas  junit runs successfully individually?

The exception thrown during maven build is:

> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

Any leads will be appreciated!

Comment: I believe JUnit works file from IDE but not command line. If you run 'mvn test' from IDE, it may fail. Because certificate might not be accessible when running from command line, but accessible for IDE

Comment: @Naveen no, even when i run the junit from command line as a single test "mvn clean test -Dtest=your.package.TestClassName", it executes sucessfully, without any exception. The exception is thrown only during "mvn clean install"

Comment: can you try "mvn clean test" ? I think it may fail. I think exception is not coming from "your.package.TestClassName", there could be different which is triggering this error

Comment: @Naveen yes it is failing with all other tests :"mvn clean test". Any solution?